# Nuxt 3 impossible to run dev

Tags: nuxtjs3

For some reason i cannot start a nuxt project.
you can find the error message i get when i do an "npm run dev" just after trying to install a new nuxt project :

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'modules')

at _sfc_main.setup (./node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/components/nuxt-root.vue:67:16)
at callWithErrorHandling (./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:157:22)
at setupStatefulComponent (./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:7107:29)
at setupComponent (./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:7062:11)
at renderComponentVNode (./node_modules/@vue/server-renderer/dist/server-renderer.cjs.js:172:17)
at renderToString (./node_modules/@vue/server-renderer/dist/server-renderer.cjs.js:446:26)
at Object.renderToString$1 [as renderToString] (./.nuxt/dev/index.mjs:472:24)
at Object.renderToString (./node_modules/vue-bundle-renderer/dist/runtime.mjs:173:40)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async ./.nuxt/dev/index.mjs:521:21

I am on Mac 12.5 Monterey, node version v16.17.0, npm version 8.15.0

Did someone encounter the same problem?

Comment: Hi, could you give us the exact steps you did here? Should be working fine, especially on Mac.

Comment: i updated node first, then did "npx nuxi init baby", after "npm install" to install the dependencies and finally "npm run dev"

Comment: Could you try with yarn? Maybe there are some unmet dependencies?

Comment: I tried another way of install: instead of "npx nuxi init" i did "yarn create nuxt-app". It resolve my problem of having to start an app but not why npx nuxi doesn't work. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Isn't `yarn create nuxt-app` creating a Nuxt2 app? I meant to use `yarn` for the package installation.

Comment: I just tried with yarn for the dependencies and the problem persist.

Comment: The error message in the terminal is as follow [Vue warn]: inject() can only be used inside setup() or functional components.
[Vue warn]: Server rendering context not provided. Make sure to only call useSSRContext() conditionally in the server build.
[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of setup function 
  at <NuxtRoot>

Comment: There are quite few issues similar to that one on Github, you may maybe track some of them there: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues?q=is%3Aissue+inject%28%29+can+only+be+used+inside+setup%28%29

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It looks like it comes from the version 3.0.0 rc9. Someone propose to downgrade to version 8. I did that and it looks fine for now.

Comment: Try the latest RC10

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading to RC8 in the meantime fixed the issue.

Or upgrade to RC10.

Comment: unfortunatly even upgrading to rc10 didn't solved the issue. I need to stay in RC8 for the meantime. https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/7609 in this thread the issue is partly addressed.